# Attempting to setup and use torctl but having issues

Tags: python, tor, pytorctl

Following [this](http://sacharya.com/tag/pytorctl/) walkthrough I did the following:

1. Install Tor (did this manually, not via win-get)
2. Installed privoxy

Trying to run:

```
tor --hash-password mypassword
```

From the command line I get

```
tor is not a recognized command...
```

I **do** have tor installed.

My goal here is to run tor via torctl in Python - and be able to change my IP address.

Running the sample script of:

```
from TorCtl import TorCtl
import urllib2

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'
headers={'User-Agent':user_agent}

def request(url):
    def _set_urlproxy():
        proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http" : "127.0.0.1:8118"})
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support)
        urllib2.install_opener(opener)
    _set_urlproxy()
    request=urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)
    return urllib2.urlopen(request).read()

def renew_connection():
    conn = TorCtl.connect(controlAddr="127.0.0.1", controlPort=9051, passphrase="your_password")
    conn.send_signal("NEWNYM")
    conn.close()

for i in range(0, 10):
    renew_connection()
    print request("http://icanhazip.com/")
```

I get the following back:

```
C:\Users\USER>python C:\temp\py_tor.py
Failed to establish socket: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\temp\py_tor.py", line 22, in <module>
    renew_connection()
  File "C:\temp\py_tor.py", line 18, in renew_connection
    conn.send_signal("NEWNYM")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_signal'
```

Answer (score 1):

`tor --hash-password` says it is not a recognized command because it is not in your `PATH` environment variable on Windows.

Just run `C:\tor\tor.exe` replacing `C:\tor` with wherever you installed it to.

Also since you are on Windows, running `tor --hash-password password` won't show any output unless you pipe it to more so you should use:

```
C:\tor\tor.exe --hash-password PASSWORD | more
```

The error `10061` is because by default Tor does not listen on the control port `9051` so you need to edit the `torrc` config file and add `ControlPort 9051` so it will listen for control connections which you will use to issue the `NEWNYM` signal to switch circuits (change IPs).

Answer (score 0):

Quick note: TorCtl, the library you're trying to use, was [deprecated in 2012](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/torctl-deprecation-and-stem-plans). While it's still functional you might want to take a look at [Stem](https://stem.torproject.org/) or [Txtorcon](https://txtorcon.readthedocs.org/).